# How to delete Rds instance along with Rds cluster using boto3 in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-rds

I need to delete the RDS instance and RDS cluster using boto3

**Note : I am creating the RDS instance under the cluster in Amazon console.**

I used the below codes however getting error:

> Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': expected an indented block (lambda_function.py, line 25)

```
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')

    # Get list of regions
    regions = ec2.describe_regions().get('Regions',[] )

    # Iterate over regions
    for region in regions:

        # Running following for a particular region
        print ("*************** Checking region  --   %s " % region['RegionName'])
        reg=region['RegionName']

    ####### deleting rds cluster ###############

    print ("++++++++++++++ Deleting RDS cluster ++++++++++++++")
    client = boto3.client('rds')
    response = client.describe_db_instance(Filters=[{'Name': 'string'}]
    for instance in response ["DBInstances"]:
       print ("About to delete %s | in %s" % (instance['DBInstanceIdentifier']))
       response = client.delete_db_instance(DBInstanceIdentifier=instance['DBInstanceIdentifier'])
       SkipFinalSnapshot=True
       DeleteAutomatedBackups=True
```

I need to delete RDS cluster and RDS db instances

NOTE: It would be better if it is possible in all regions in my account

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop at the bottom is not indented properly, should be something like below:

```py
    for cluster in result ["rds"]:
        print ("About to delete %s | in %s" % (cluster['DBInstanceIdentifier']))
        response = client.delete_db_instance(DBInstanceIdentifier=cluster['DBInstanceIdentifier'])
        SkipFinalSnapshot=True
        DeleteAutomatedBackups=True
```

Comment: @ Biplob Biswas  I am still facing issues with deletion.Do you have any idea how the script should be? I need to delete the Rds instance in all regions using boto3?

Comment: @MuneeshDuRaipandi Can you give more details with the question? how are you creating the rds instance, cloudformation or cli or console? is it part fo a cluster or just standalone instance? update your question maybe and then I can update the answer as well

Comment: @ Biplob Biswas  I have updated the question. I am creating RDS instance under cluster in AWS console and I need to delete the cluster and RDS instance using boto3.

Answer (score 0):

Effectively, to delete a db cluster from boto3, you need to:

1. Delete all instances in the cluster
2. Delete the cluster

Note: both are required. If you do not delete the cluster, you will have a cluster with zero instances, and if you do not delete the instances, you will get the following error:

```
botocore.errorfactory.InvalidDBClusterStateFault: An error occurred (InvalidDBClusterStateFault) when calling the DeleteDBCluster operation: Cluster cannot be deleted, it still contains DB instances in non-deleting state.
```

Great - so how do we do it?

```
instance_name = 'instance-name'
rds.delete_db_instance(
    DBInstanceIdentifier=instance_name,
    SkipFinalSnapshot=False,
    DeleteAutomatedBackups=True,
)
cluster_name = 'cluster-name.cluster-abcdefgh.rds.amazonaws.com'
rds.delete_db_cluster(
    DBClusterIdentifier=cluster_name,
    SkipFinalSnapshot=False,
    FinalDBSnapshotIdentifier=cluster_name,
)
```

---

A more proper solution would be to describe your clusters (`rds.describe_clusters`), then to describe the instances on those clusters (`rds.describe_db_instances`). As you iterate through the instances on each cluster, you delete each instance. After you have deleted all instances on the cluster, you can delete the cluster.

The below is untested but is definitely close; community, feel free to update where needed.

```
# pull our rds clusters
db_clusters = rds.describe_db_clusters()

# for each cluster
for cluster in db_clusters['DBClusters']:
    # grab the cluster identifier
    cluster_name = cluster['DBClusterIdentifier']
    db_instances = rds.describe_db_instances(Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'db-cluster-id',
            'Values': [
                cluster_name,
            ]
        })

    # for each instance on this cluster
    for instance in db_instances['DBInstances']:
        instance_name = instance['DBInstanceIdentifier']
        print(f'Now deleting {instance_name}'.)        
        # delete the instance
        rds.delete_db_instance(
            DBInstanceIdentifier=instance_name,
            SkipFinalSnapshot=False,
            DeleteAutomatedBackups=True,
        )
    # now that we have finished deleting the instances, we can delete the cluster
    print(f'Now deleting {cluster_name}'.)        
    rds.delete_db_cluster(
        DBClusterIdentifier=cluster_name,
        SkipFinalSnapshot=False,
        FinalDBSnapshotIdentifier=current_stage_db1a_cluster_name,
    )
```